# Q# environment inconsistencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, q#

I have tried installing the Q# developement kit twice and have the same interesting abnormalities each time. Default program displayed below.

**First inconsistency:**

> All of my sample code works from the Git repository, but when I create
>   a new Q# project in its own directory I always get the following errors with a
>   blank brand new Q# application:

[Image of the 3 errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCnJF.png)

1. Error: Reference to unknown namespace Microsoft.Quantum.PrimitiveQSharpApplication1C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Programing(most recent)\Q#\QSharpApplication1\QSharpApplication1\Operation.qs4
2. Error: The command ""C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Programing(most recent)\Q#\QSharpApplication1\packages\Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit.0.1.1712.901-preview\build..\tools\qsc\qsc.exe" --input "Operation.qs" --references "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Programing(most recent)\Q#\QSharpApplication1\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.4.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll" --outputpath obj\qsharp\src\" exited with code -1.QSharpApplication1
3. Error: The namespace body is invalidQSharpApplication1C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Programing(most recent)\Q#\QSharpApplication1\QSharpApplication1\Operation.qs1

**Second inconsistency:**

> When I run the Git Repository samples, there are no warning messages that I need any `NuGet Packages`. Then I create my own Q# project and like
>   magic we have `Nuget Package` issues, but nothing to install for them
>   according to visual studio. The warning messages also consist of messages regarding `build dependencies` and `framework dependencies`, that again are not there in the sample Git code. Only when I create a new project.

[Picture of Indirect Dependency Warnings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMo1E.png) - multiple instances of warning for multiple references

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Warning:        The primary reference "Microsoft.Quantum.Canon" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Microsoft.Quantum.MetaData, Version=0.1.1712.901, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40866b40fd95c7f5" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2".   QSharpApplication1

[Picture of .NET Framework Version warning.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAGfa.png) - multiple instances of warning for multiple references

- Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Warning:        The primary reference "Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2". QSharpApplication1

**Question:**

> How can I fix the errors that occur when creating the new Q# application? As well as the `Nuget` warning errors that say I must reinstall `NuGet Packages` even though Visual Studio doesn't find any packages to be reinstalled.

If anyone can help me get the environment correct, I would appreciate it greatly!

**P.S.** If I just comment out the Git Repository's code I can work in one of their samples but would prefer not to have to do that.

**Default Operation.qs file:**

```
namespace Quantum.QSharpApplication1
{
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive;
    open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;

    operation Operation () : ()
    {
        body
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Default Driver.cs file:**

```
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;
using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Simulators;

namespace Quantum.QSharpApplication1
{
    class Driver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

and also change target cpu x64